# how to remove xmlns attribute with namespace but not remove namespace prefix in element tag using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

i have a xml like this,

```
<article>

  <ce:jid xmlns:ce="http://www.elsevier.com">CQG</ce:jid>

</article>
```

i want to remove the xmln:namespace only,

and expected output is;

```
<article>

<ce:jid>CQG</ce:jid>

</article>
```

Comment: the namespace `ce` must be declared in the root element if you want a valid XML.

Comment: This may help, as I have a similar issue https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1167775/Remove-namespace-from-XML

Answer (score 0):

If that is the whole output XML document you require then you can't achieve it with XSLT because the output is not namespace-well-formed - the `ce` prefix must be declared *somewhere*, either on the `jid` element itself or on one of its ancestors up the tree.

If this is a *fragment* of the output then you need to ensure the `ce` prefix binding appears on one of the ancestors above the point where this fragment is inserted, and the XML serializer should automatically produce what you want (it doesn't need to re-declare the namespace if it is already in scope on an ancestor).